# bootstrap3 datetimepicker div cut off calendar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I would like that the calendar to appear outside the .row div but div must have both scrolls bar.

If div have overflow popierty cut off calendar. 
I tried set widgetParent to body, but then position of calendar is wrong. Not near input.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 150px; height: 200px; overflow: scroll;">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' style="width: 40px;" class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/8jpmkcr5/155/)

Comment: What is the question? You want the calendar to appear outside the .row div so the user doesn't have to scroll?

Comment: exacly, I want the calendar to appear outside the .row div

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  //  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({widgetParent: 'body'});
});
```

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: show;
}

.row #datetimepicker1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10001;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try not to write inline css , instead you can give class and then write css in that class.

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for tip, but I used inline css only for this example, I know is this the wrong practice.
This not solve my problem, because I need have scroll bars. Please see example, I updated it.

Answer (score -1):

Change your .row's overflow to '`show`.'
So:

```
<div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 150px; height: 200px; overflow: show;">
```

Comment: This not solve my problem, because I need have scroll bars. Please see example, I updated it.